# SQL Functions have or not DML commands inside it?

Tags: sql-server

Can I use Data Manipulation Language commands in inside of Function?

Comment: No! And really: This is something you should not aks the community. Just google for `SQL Server function dml` and you'll get tons of results...

Comment: Have you tried to use DML inside functions? The server itself could give you the answer in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.

The functions perform an action such as a complex calculation, and returns the result of that action as a value. The return value can be a scalar value (single) or a table.

To use DML statements, automatically, use stored procedures.

You can use functions within stored procedures, but not vice versa.

Take a look: [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186755(v=sql.110).aspx)